# How do you use the http.server python module to run HTML+Javascript+CSS?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, server

I am trying to create a simple python server using the http.server module. My python code looks like this:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class helloHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path == '/mainprogram.html'
        try:
            file_to_open = open('mainprogram.html').read()
            self.send_response(200)
        except:
            file_to_open = "file not found"
            self.send_response(404)
        self.send_header('content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(file_to_open, 'utf-8'))

def main():
    PORT = 8000
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT),helloHandler)
    print('Server running on port %s' % PORT)
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This serves my HTML page on the server but it doesn't run my javascript and CSS files. So the skeleton of my page is there i.e. text, buttons, search bars but none of the functionality is there and the styles aren't applied.

I have written separate CSS and Javascript files and have included them in my HTML file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="scriptfile.js"><script>
```

Please help! I am a beginner to all this so I have no clue

Comment: The issue is that your web server needs to serve the `styles.css` and `scriptfile.js` files as well. However, if all you're doing is serving static files, I would recommend putting your static files in a directory and running `python3 -m http.server`. If you need an actual server, `http.server` is not actually recommended for production and is really meant more as a command-line tool. I would recommend using [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) instead if you're set on using Python. Then, you'll need to set up a static directory.

Comment: @AlexanderCai, flask or djandgo are not really for serving statics either. Somethng like nginx would be much better.